# MATLAB: combination boxplot of different length vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, concatenation, boxplot

I have three vectors if different size (86x1 double), (61x1 double) and (10x1 double).

I try:

```
figure
boxplot([x1,x2,x3])
```

but get "error using horzcat, dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent".

I've tried transposing the vectors but it looks like it combines these into one group and does a boxplot for that. i.e. if i have

```
boxplot([x1,x2,x3],'Labels','thing1','thing2','thing3')
```

I get:

"Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error using boxplot>assignUserLabels (line 1688)
There must be the same number of labels as groups or as the number
of elements in X."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x1`, `x2` and `x3` have different sizes, you cannot convert them into one large matrix. And you cannot use `boxplot(x)` syntax where x is a matrix.

In this case, you need a grouping variable:

> boxplot(x,g) creates a box plot using one or more grouping variables contained in g. boxplot produces a separate box for each set of x values that share the same g value or values.

The document came from https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html

Here is an example of how to create a grouping variable based on given inputs.

```
g1 = ones(size(x1)) * 1;
g2 = ones(size(x2)) * 2;
g3 = ones(size(x3)) * 3;
figure()
boxplot([x1; x2; x3], [g1; g2; g3], 'Labels', {'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'})
```

Comment: Could explain why this works? You just provided the answer with out any explanation.